# Must I refer to the item with id while creating hyperlinks?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm new in HTML/CSS and I am wondering if I can create something like a multi-level hyperlink.
For example, I have:

```
<section id="Sport">
    <article id="game1">
        <h2 class="titleheader">WHAT A GAME!</h2>
    </article>
    <article id="game2">
        <h2 class="titleheader">UNEXPECTED DRAW!</h2>
    </article>
</section>
```

I want all "titleheaders" to have some styling. But at the same time, I  want to put the hyperlink to the h2 "unexpected draw". Is it possible to create a hyperlink to the class item?

Comment: `href="#game2"` you can use the `:target` selector in CSS also

Comment: Yes, but this will make the link to the article. If there would be some text over it, it would make no sense.
How to use this :target selector? I read MDN and quite don't get it.

Comment: `#game2:target` would target the element when the link was clicked. you can simply add an `id` to the `h2` and use that instead

Comment: Ok, so how code of hyperlink would look like?

Comment: See my answer to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<section id="Sport">
    <article id="game1">
        <h2 class="titleheader">WHAT A GAME!</h2>
    </article>
    <article id="game1">
        <h2 class="titleheader" id="unexpected-draw">UNEXPECTED DRAW!</h2>
    </article>
</section>
```

When you need to link to it:

```
<a href="#unexpected-draw">Link text</a>
```

When you need to target it in CSS (when the link is clicked, scrolling you down to the header):

```
#unexpected-draw:target
```

or

```
h2:target
```

(this is often used to highlight or otherwise emphasize the header)

---

[`:target` CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

Comment: Well, only `#undexpected-draw{}` wouldn't work? What is this target needed for? That's the thing I quite don't get.

Comment: The [`:target`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) is a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).